# How do you pass hidden query params to a route in Angular 5?

Tags: angular

The current Angular way to pass data to a route is to add it into the routes.

Eg, In the tour of heroes guide on the offical Angular docs, an id is passed onto the hero component using the route `hero/:id`.

Without using a Service as an intermediary, or using something like Local storage to temporarily hold onto some data, `id`, in this instance, is it possible to pass the `id`?

Comment: It won't be route param if it will be hidden. You can use a storage like localStorage to store it between sessions, or store it in parent service for current session, or whatever.

Comment: Routes are not created for passing any data, except of params. Thats what is component interaction is about (services, inputs/outputs, etc.). If you really want to pass data without service, then add it as param and in destination component init you read it and remove param part, but this is considered as hack.

Comment: You can use `skipLocationChange` to suppress changing the URL at all. But that just hides it from the URL bar, the URL itself still contains the data.

Comment: @IngoBürk: skipLocationChange does not prevent to hide new queryParameters from the URL (at least tested with v 5.2.10)

Answer (score 0):

could send the information through observable

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class LoadDataService {
  private setdataEmmit = new BehaviorSubject('initial info');
  public getdataEmmit$ = this.setdataEmmit.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  sendData(data: any) {
    this.setdataEmmit.next(data)
  }
}
```

component1.ts

```
import { LoadDataService  } from '.....';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-1',
  templateUrl:'',
  styleUrls: ['']

})
export class Component1 implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private _loadDataService: LoadDataService
  ) { 
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this._loadDataService.sendData('info send');  
  }
}
```

component2.ts

```
import { LoadDataService  } from '.....';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-2',
  templateUrl:'',
  styleUrls: ['']

})
export class Component2 implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private _loadDataService: LoadDataService
  ) { 
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this._loadDataService.getdataEmmit$.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        // print: 'info send'
           // YOU ALREADY HAVE THE DATA YOU SENT FROM THE COMPONENT 1
      });
  }
}
```